# About Switching Processors

Tags: windows, laptop, cpu, switch

As I've mentioned in the title: I have a dead laptop (due to motherboard failure) and an old one (Fujitsu Amilo Pi3560) which I'm using the last 2 weeks. Yesterday I put an SSD on it, so it's a lot faster. But I'm also thinking of putting the processor of the dead one (which is an Intel i5-7200U) on the Fujitsu. I'm asking this question because I don't know if there is any problem with an upgrade like this on an old laptop. What do you think, is it considered a risky action? Are there any dangers of temperature rising like crazy if I put a newer processor on an old laptop like this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Can I put a newer processor on an old laptop like this?

You can't just *swap* the CPUs as they have a completely different socket specification.

- Fujitsu Amilo Pi3560 Processor Intel Core 2 Duo T6600
- Sockets Supported PGA478
- Package Size 35 mm x 35 mm

Source [Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor T6600 (2M Cache, 2.20 GHz, 800 MHz FSB) Product Specifications](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/37255/intel-core-2-duo-processor-t6600-2m-cache-2-20-ghz-800-mhz-fsb.html)

- Intel i5-7200U
- Sockets Supported FCBGA1356
- Package Size 42mm X 24mm

Source [Intel® Core™ i5-7200U Processor (3M Cache, up to 3.10 GHz) Product Specifications](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/95443/intel-core-i5-7200u-processor-3m-cache-up-to-3-10-ghz.html)

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you!